# Move the value along with the handle in dijit/form/HorizontalSlider

Tags: dojo

Currently i am getting the values upon sliding but I want to display the values along with the handle in dojo horizontal slider.
   I am creating the slider like this

```
    var slider = new HorizontalRangeSlider({
                name : "slider",
                value : startValue,
                //starting and end values to the slider             
                minimum : endValue,
                maximum : endValue,
                intermediateChanges : true,
                showButtons : false,
                onChange : lang.hitch(this, "setValues")
            }, this.slider).startup();

    var sliderLabelsRule = new HorizontalRule({
                container : "topDecoration",
                style:"height:5px",
                count : 2,              
                numericMargin: 1
            }, this.sliderRule);
            this.sliderLabelsRule.startup();

            //create the labels object
    var sliderLabelsTop = new HorizontalRuleLabels({
                container : "topDecoration",
                style : "font-size: 14px;",
            //array that contains the label values
                labels : array,
            }, this.sliderLabelsTop);
            sliderLabelsTop.startup();
```

And the template is like this

```
<div>
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="slider">

        <div data-dojo-attach-point="sliderRule"></div>

        <ol data-dojo-attach-point="sliderLabelsTop"></ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now i have to display the value upon sliding the slider rule just below the slider handle, How to do this in dojo?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @ user2182349 i have added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make use of the HorizontalRangeSlider attach points and we can place the value that you want to show by placing there.

HorizontalSRangeSlider has two attach point sliderHandle and sliderHandleMax,we can place the value there like this,

```
                this.horizontalSlider = new HorizontalRangeSlider({
                name : "slider",
                value : this.sliderMinMax,
                minimum : this.sliderMinMax[0],
                maximum : this.sliderMinMax[1],
                intermediateChanges : false,
                showButtons : false,
                onChange : lang.hitch(this, "callOnchange")
            }, this.slider);
            this.horizontalSlider.startup();

            this.horizontalSliderRule = new HorizontalRule({
                container : "topDecoration",
                style:"height:5px",
                count : 2,              
                numericMargin: 1
            }, this.sliderRule);
            this.horizontalSliderRule.startup();

this.horizontalSliderRule.sliderHandle.innerHTML = value //your value to show
```